# Open login page , insert logon information and click loginbutton 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open a logon page like www.site.com/login.php

insert username and password

and login button be invoke .

All of this should be done progroamlly in a server (not in a browser )

is it possible to do thsi ?

Comment: What is the goal of this, to let an ASP.NET site automatically log you in to another PHP based site?

Comment: yes , if possible , I want to download a file after login .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to preserve a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) instance between the login POST request (that presumably sets a login cookie) and further requests, if you want to trigger the requests as a logged-in user.

```
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();            
        var loginData = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
            // be carefull to use the same keys/names as the login form
            { "username", "LightWing" },
            { "password", "l33tPwD" } 
        };
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.../login.php");
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.Method = "POST";

        // build the POST data
        byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Join("&", loginData.AllKeys.Select(x => string.Concat(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x), "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(loginData[x])))));
        request.ContentLength = dataBuffer.LongLength;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Flush();
        }
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // do some reading if you want..
        }

        // now _cookieJar should contain the login cookie...
        // you can trigger further requests as a logged in user:
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.../restrictedPage.php");
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar; // reuse them cookies!
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // read the restricted page response
        }
```

I have also written a simple utility that helps you to scrape Asp.net WebForms pages that use postbacks. You can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/m0sa/aspxsessionscraper).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a POST request to wherever the login button submits.
Just pass the username and password within the request.

Answer (score 0):

Every login page often are in this format:

```
<form action="login.extention" method="post or get">
<input name="username" type="text" />
<input name="password" type="password" />
</form>
```

You must send your information to the action page by get or post.(usually post)

Answer (score 0):

I did the same for one of the small projects

I add the Hyperlink in .aspx page and after clicking it Automatically login me to the external site

on page_load call the following code

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "javascript:__doExternalPost(\"http://www.xyz.com/login.jsp\");";

if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
{
       this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("username", USERNAME);                                                        
       this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("password", PASSWORD);
}
```

in .aspx page add the following javascript

```
function __doExternalPost(targetUrl) 
{
    theForm.__VIEWSTATE.value = "";
    theForm.encoding = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    theForm.action = targetUrl;
    theForm.target = "_blank";
    theForm.submit();
}
```

Hopefully it will do some help